# Listed in Razor 2 Nobody on the internet knows an answer

Tags: email, razor, razor-2, razorengine, razorgenerator

I wanted to start a small campaign of about 400-500 emails and I tested the email with mail-tester.com

The problem is that I've got these 2 errors and nobody on the internet knows an answer for it: 
-2.43   RAZOR2_CF_RANGE_E8_51_100   Razor2 gives engine 8 confidence level above 50%
-1.729  RAZOR2_CHECK    Listed in Razor2 (http://razor.sf.net/)
This happends for both the domain and subdomain. I tried sending an email with a completely changed text (something about animals I've found on wikipedia) and without signature, I even tried sending an empty email and got the same misterious errors.

I tried sending the exact same mail + signature from another domain and it worked perfectly without any error.

1. What should I try next, considering the fact that it's impossible to change the domain name?
2. How popular is SpamAssasin with its Razor 2 or is it maybe irrelevant?
3. Should I wait or on the contrary send as many emails as possible to detect clean traffic?

Thanks